# Using のに in a sentence, and expressing "third to last"

Tags: grammar, meaning, syntax, sentence

私は最後じゃなかったのに、最後の二人の女子たちがレースの途中で走るのをやめて、歩いてゴールインしたので、私があたかもレースの最後のように感じました。

I'm writing a sakubun on when I arrived third to last in a race back when I went to middle school.

In my sentence I wanted to say: "Even if I didn't arrive last, since the last two girls stopped running in the middle and reached the finish line while walking, I felt just like I arrived last" (meaning: I felt extremely disappointed because my performance was a failure even if I never stopped running unlike the two other girls).

Does the sentence I wrote make any sense to you? Did I use のに right? Do you have any suggestions to improve my sentence? Moreover, what is the best way to say "third to last"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you use のに perfectly fits into this sentence, representing disappointment between the actual situation and your expectation. Your entire sentence is very naturally written too.

However,

> レースの最後

only means "the last phase of the race", not"the last one in the race". You could use ビリ "the bottom (in a competition)" or 最下位 "the lowest in rank" to refer to the status.

> 私があたかも最下位のように感じました。
>   私があたかもビリのように感じました。

Also, there are many ways of saying "third to last", that are applicable in this scene, but each one has its own scope:

> 最後から三番目／三人<sup>*</sup>目 (for something has the first and the last in order)
>   下から三番目／三人<sup>*</sup>目 (for something has the top and the bottom)
>   ビリから三番目／三人<sup>*</sup>目 (just see above for this)
>   最下位から三番目／三人<sup>*</sup>目 (...and this)

<sup>(* change the counter according to competitors' identity)</sup>